# How to add date and time to filename in DOS?

Tags: batch-file

I want to add date and time value in filename and then I want to move that file to near by folder.

Here I'm using below commands to capture date and time :

```
set dt=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~,8%

echo %dt%
```

Then I am using copy command as below :

```
copy result_accnum.txt C:\ramki_windows\batch_practise\Query_stored\result_accnum_%dt%.txt
```

but nothing useful. I am getting error as "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.".

Comment: The colon (`:`) isn't allowed in a file name. It's reserved for delimiting drive letters, etc, in DOS path names.

Comment: could you please tell me little clear,because that colon(:) denotes the drive letter of my destination path.

Comment: but for the same copy command mentioned above,if i am removing '%dt%' alone then it is working fine...like below                                copy result_accnum.txt C:\ramki_windows\batch_practise\Query_stored\result_accnum_1.txt
        1 file(s) copied.

Comment: You mean you have a file named, for example, `22-04-2014_13:20:30` and it's happy with that? When I try to make such a file name, I get the error you are describing.

Comment: As a side note, this is obviously for a windows cmd prompt as DOS only supports 8.3 filenames.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The colon (`:`) isn't allowed in a file name. It's reserved for delimiting drive letters, etc, in DOS path names. You could use underscore (`_`) instead:

```
set dt=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

Note that there is no leading zero for times before 10 am. If this is important for your file name format, then it could be done as follows:

```
set hh=%time:~0,2%
if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set hh=0%hh:~1,1%   

set dt=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%_%hh%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

Comment: I get a trailing space after the %hh% in the second example, which is inconvenient for filenames. To overcome this I use set dt=%dt: =%

Comment: @ThePuternerd not sure why you see a space. When I do the second method, I do not get a trailing space after the `%hh%`.

Comment: I get it when the hour is 1 digit. Windows 7.

Comment: @ThePuternerd I just tried it and not able to reproduce your issue. The time currently is 06:49am. I got, `21-07-2017_06_49_21` as my resulting string for `dt`.

Answer (score 7):

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-8 delims=:./ " %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET datetime=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)
```

This will calculate it as date_hour_min_sec and store it in a variable called as datetime. 
e.g.

```
24042015_19_10_12
```

you can use this datetime variable directly appended to your filename if you know how to do it in DOS (its simple : 
`set filename= sampletextfor_%datetime%.txt` will give you `sampletextfor_24042015_19_10_12.txt` or whatever file).

---

### how it works?

the for command goes through the string formed by %date%*%time%. %date%*%time% gives you the value of date time in cmd (system variables).
the token specifies which elements do you want to pick up based on the delimiter.
the delimiter specifies what to consider as a new element say for e.g. /:. are delims here. also " " (space) is a delimiter (you can see I have left one after /)

---

Hope it helps thanks! :)

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work reliably, so this is the solution I used.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is correct from lurker above but HH needs only first two characters or you will get spaces in filename if hour is less than 2 digits

```
set hh=%time:~0,2%
if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set hh=0%hh:~1,1%   

set dt=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%_%hh:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

for those who like MM-dd-yyyy

```
set hh=%time:~0,2%
if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set hh=0%hh:~1,1%   

set dt=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%hh:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete batch file that worked for me.

```
@echo off
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "tokens=1-8 delims=:./ " %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET datetime=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)

copy result_accnum.txt "C:\ramki_windows\batch_practise\Query_stored\result_accnum_!datetime!.txt"
```

The file created was named as result_accnum_Fri0106_2017_14_54.txt

While to create a directory based on timestamp, following worked for me.

```
@echo off
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "tokens=1-8 delims=:./ " %%G IN ("%date%_%time%") DO (
SET datetime=%%G%%H%%I_%%J_%%K
)

SET dirname=C:\ramki_windows\batch_practise\Query_stored\result_accnum_!datetime!
if not exist %dirname% mkdir %dirname%

copy result_accnum.txt %dirname%\result_accnum_!datetime!.txt
```

Comment: It's the [same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29849290/463115) as the one of Sarthak. I can't see any better/other approach to get the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

For time before 10:00 the file name will have as space ie name_11_11_2014_ 9_45.txt and copy will fail. You need to add quotations ie `copy name.txt "name%dt%.txt"`