# create a batch file with folder name provided by user

Tags: date, batch-file, xcopy

i have created a batch file which copy the data of one folder into another. But after copying i want to give the naem as a folder name. I am not able to. Please give your suggestions. sorry for changing the question. but now i need this.

This is my code.

```
@echo off

:: variables

echo Backing up file

set /P source=Enter source folder:

set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:

set listfile=xcopy /L

set xcopy=xcopy /S/E/V/Q/F/H

%listfile% %source% %destination% 

echo files will be copy press enter to proceed

pause

%xcopy% %source% %destination% 

pause
```

Comment: where in your code is your attempt to set the Date on the destination folder? hint: read HELP SET and look for the %DATE% dynamic variable.

Comment: will you please help me regarding how to give the name to the sub folder after my backup is completed. i want my backup into that particular folder.

Comment: give `md %destination%-%date%` a try

Answer (score 0):

I take it (based on comments) you want to append the date and time to the destination folder. As shown below, use one set command to convert date&time to a format you can use in a folder name ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226233/how-to-add-date-and-time-to-filename-in-dos))  and another to set the new folder name. After the xcopy, use the move command to rename the folder. (See cited source about keeping quote marks around the %datename% folder.)

```
@echo off

echo Backing up file
    :: variables
    set /P source=Enter source folder:
    set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:

    :: This converts the date and time environmental variables to a
    :: format you can use in a folder name.
    set dt=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%

    :: Set the new folder name appending the dt variable.  
    :: %destination% needs to be a folder name only, not a full path
    set datename=%destination%%dt%
    set listfile=xcopy /L
    set xcopy=xcopy /S/E/V/Q/F/H

    %listfile% %source% %destination% 

echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
pause

    %xcopy% %source% %destination% 
pause

    :: This renames %destination% to the %datename% you set. 
    :: Keep quote marks. %datename% can have a space depending on time
    MOVE "%destination%" "%datename%"
```

Comment: If you just want to rename the folder, use the move command (shown) and don't set the vars for datename. (Also, you obviously know how to get a folder name from user now, so you should change your question.)